# Unable to reverse Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've just started with Javascript and learning the Jquery library, I have this simple box which I created in CSS and was animating it with Jquery, when a button is clicked the box gets bigger but when another is clicked it returns to its original size.
I've got the button to make the box bigger to work just fine but I can't seem to get the button to make it smaller to actually make it smaller.

```js
$(".big").click(function() {
  $(".box1").animate({
    height: '+=150px',

  });
});

$(".small").click(function() {
  $(".box1").animate({
    width: '-=150px;'
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box1'></div>
<button type='button' class='big'>big</button>
<button type='button' class='small'>small</button>
```

I don't understand why it won't work, sorry if this comes across as a silly question.

Comment: For a start, you add height, but subtract width - was that intentional?

Comment: @freedomn-m nope it turned out to be another mistake on my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is that you added `;` in `height: '-=150px;'`

If you remove it it's working just fine.

**Demo**

```js
$(".big").click(function() {
  $(".box1").animate({
    height: '+=150px',

  });
});

$(".small").click(function() {
  $(".box1").animate({
    height: '-=150px'
  });
});
```

```css
.box1{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background-color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small">small</div>
<div class="big">big</div>
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, it was such a simple answer which I could've figured out if I actually spent more time looking, thank you for your help

Comment: @MrZooSuit No problem, happy to help.